# Org and EIN (IPython): No output for print

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ein

I am using EIN in Org blocks, as explained on the [GitHub page for EIN](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook#ob-ein). So I use `ein-python` as the language for Org blocks (instead of `python`).

All seems to work well (for example displaying data from arrays, or displaying images), except when trying to `print` in the buffer: there is no output in the block results. However, it works with `python` as the block language.

The following minimal example shows the problem:

```
#+begin_src python :session localhost :results output
print("Hello")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Hello

#+NAME: ca60b6cf-8304-4c47-b458-559dea7d9ab0
#+begin_src ein-python :session localhost :results output
print("Hello")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: ca60b6cf-8304-4c47-b458-559dea7d9ab0
```

Above, `Hello` is not displayed the block results in the case of `ein-python`.

What causes this problem?

Comment: See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58239/ein-org-mode-results-raw-drawer/58256?noredirect=1#comment90895_58256) where somebody else has similar problems.

Comment: @NickD I had seen this post; I am not using Anaconda, but working with a virtual environment, and my variable `org-babel-python-command` is set to `python` (which is python 3.6.9 in my environment). Changing it to for example `python3` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Then it may be a problem with Jupyter (or more likely with ob-ein). You might want to submit an issue at the EIN github site.

Comment: @NickD Could it be that I need to install `ob-ein` from the GitHub package? On the EIN GitHub page (see link in my question), they do not require to have this package: they only require to specify `ein` in the Org Babel languages... I installed EIN via MELPA and I am not sure whether I have everything needed...

Comment: I don't know: I don't use EIN - hence my suggestion to submit an issue at the github site.

Comment: @NickD Just for my information, do you know of other means to plot graphs inline in Org than using EIN? Is it possible to have the same functionalities as in a notebook by using only the `python` babel language?

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment: I know next to nothing about notebooks. Of course, notebooks are built on python, so in some sense the answer is "yes", but that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html

```
#+NAME: BCA82DE1-F7E2-42EF-A37F-84CB9C2AFD0C
#+begin_src ein-python :session http://localhost:8888/frank_ein_inline_image.ipynb :results output 
import sys
print(sys.version)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: BCA82DE1-F7E2-42EF-A37F-84CB9C2AFD0C
: 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 10:15:43) 
: [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
```